# Attributes error on importing Magento 2 products

Tags: magento2.2, attributes, product-attribute, import, import-products

Im tryin to import products.csv on my Magento 2.2.6 website, but i receive the below error.

```
1. Value for 'news_to_date' attribute contains incorrect value in row(s): 1, 2, 3, 8, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 340, 344, 348, 350, 354, 355, 356, 363, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 391, 445, 448, 451, 465, 466, 467, 470, 472, 473, 475, 476, 477, 480, 482, 487, 493, 494, 495, 499, 507, 543, 592, 599, 633, 648, 649, 776, 819
2. Value for 'special_to_date' attribute contains incorrect value in row(s): 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 32, 33, 42, 43, 52, 111, 168, 177, 234, 265, 266, 271, 318, 323, 324, 329, 330, 331, 334, 339, 341, 342, 343, 346, 359, 360, 368, 369, 370, 390, 395, 396, 397, 401, 402, 403, 404, 406, 407, 408, 409, 418, 422, 429, 431, 498, 506, 537, 569, 576, 578, 580, 584, 589, 594, 597, 600, 606, 612, 613, 629, 631, 635, 637, 638, 647, 651, 657, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 668, 671, 672, 680, 682, 683, 724, 725, 735, 736, 754, 759, 761, 764, 765, 766, 768, 778, 826, 827, 845, 847, 848, 849, 870, 871, 872, 874, 875
3. Value for 'special_from_date' attribute contains incorrect value in row(s): 47, 125, 126, 134, 149, 156, 165, 172, 197, 333, 335, 338, 345, 349, 352, 357, 358, 367, 392, 393, 394, 400, 405, 410, 411, 414, 415, 416, 419, 420, 421, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 430, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 441, 446, 447, 449, 450, 452, 455, 457, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 468, 469, 474, 478, 479, 481, 486, 492, 497, 500, 501, 502, 503, 505, 508, 509, 510, 513, 514, 515, 517, 518, 519, 520, 524, 527, 529, 530, 531, 533, 534, 535, 541, 542, 545, 546, 547, 548, 551, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 568, 570, 571, 573, 574, 575, 577, 581, 582, 583, 588, 598, 601, 608, 618, 620, 627, 628, 632, 636, 644, 645, 650, 656, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 681, 697, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 721, 722, 723, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 747, 755, 757, 762, 769, 772, 773, 775, 777, 820, 824, 825, 846, 850, 868, 892
4. Value for 'news_from_date' attribute contains incorrect value in row(s): 538, 544, 552, 694, 695, 698, 699, 700, 701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 726, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 745, 746, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752, 753, 756, 758, 760
```

I dont know how to skip these. I have no clue what these attribute values are. Can somebody help? Download the Products.csv file here: http://informaticsdemo.com/Products.csv (3MB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All date attributes need to be imported in the following format YYYY-mm-dd.

Comment: Thanks @gabehou for your reply. It works.

Comment: Thanks @gabehou it works.